# Cylinder on double edge with different angles - normal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, equilibrium

I'm looking for normal forces for this case:
[image]

So, let's say it's a case with cylinder of weight G in wedge with two different angles. What are the values of normal forces? It's confusing for me, because components of normal forces in horizontal don't give me equilibrium. Which part am I missing?

**EDIT ON 18th January 2022:**

I was thinking about this problem, because I was solving another one with great people here. I think that the first answer is not correct. The reason is that again I took normal force as a main force, not as a component. Weight G is divided into two vertical forces and these forces then produce a normal force on the inclination. And these normal forces are components of vertical forces. The part which is good is that we don't produce too much error with the numbers, beacuse of small angles.
Everything is on the sketch:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no friction on any of the surfaces, by resolving the forces vertically and horizontally, you have
$$N_{\alpha}\cos\alpha+N_{\beta}\cos\beta=G$$
and
$$N_{\alpha}\sin\alpha=N_{\beta}\sin\beta$$

You can solve these simultaneously to find the normal reactions.

Comment: Of course. So final answer is: $N_\beta=\frac{G}{\frac{\sin\beta}{\sin\alpha}\cos\alpha+\cos\beta}$ and $N_\alpha=N_\beta\frac{\sin\beta}{\sin\alpha}$. Any mathematical recommendations for simplifying? At least first one to make it shorter? Thanks.

Comment: I reviewed this question because I'm curentlly working on this one: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49271/rack-on-rack-vertical-force. I think that here we made the same mistake of not corectlly writing the force components. Weight G is divided in two parts, vertical forces, which act on each slope vertically. Then we need to put these vertical forces to components normal to slope and parallel with slope and write the equilibrium equations. I will try to review this tomorrow and post here.